# .NET XPath starting from a specific element and backreferencing to it

Tags: .net, xpath

I have (actually going to have) an app where I need to find a specific xml element (call it element A) using XPath and then find another element (element B) referenced by eleement A.
Example:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var s = @"
<Root>
    <Start refId = ""5""/>
    <Start refId = ""6""/>
    <Item id = ""5""/>
    <Item id = ""6""/>
</Root>
";

        var doc = new XmlDocument();
        using (var sr = new StringReader(s))
        {
            doc.Load(sr);
        }

        XmlNode nodeA = doc.SelectNodes(@"Root/Start[1]")[0];
        var selected = nodeA.SelectNodes(@"/Root/Item[@id = @refId]");
    }
```

Here nodeA is the node A that I can find. selected is a collection of nodes B that I can't find. My problem is in [@id = @refId] where I want to return to nodeA that I start from and get the value of its attribute "refId", but I can't find a way how. Is this possible to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** The only way I can see accomplishing what you describe below in the comments is to use LINQ to XML, XPath variables, or define your own `current()` function. XPath variables and current functions are a bit of a pain because they require writing your own classes to handle them, but you can use these relatively simple generic classes:

```
public class VariableContext : XsltContext
{
    IXPathNavigable CurrentNode;

    Dictionary<string, object> Values = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    public void SetValue(string name, object value)
    {
        Values[name] = value;
    }
    public void SetCurrentNode(IXPathNavigable currentNode)
    {
        CurrentNode = currentNode;
    }

    public override int CompareDocument(string baseUri, string nextbaseUri)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override bool PreserveWhitespace(System.Xml.XPath.XPathNavigator node)
    {
        return false;
    }

    public override IXsltContextFunction ResolveFunction(string prefix, string name, System.Xml.XPath.XPathResultType[] ArgTypes)
    {
        if (name.Equals("current"))
        {
            return new CurrentFunction(CurrentNode);
        }
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override IXsltContextVariable ResolveVariable(string prefix, string name)
    {
        object value;
        if (Values.TryGetValue(name, out value))
        {
            return new ContextVariable(name, value);
        }
        throw new ApplicationException("Unknown variable: " + name);
    }

    public override bool Whitespace
    {
        get { return false; }
    }
}

public class ContextVariable : IXsltContextVariable
{
    private string m_name;
    private object m_parameter;

    public ContextVariable(string name, object parameter)
    {
        m_name = name;
        m_parameter = parameter;

        IXPathNavigable navigable = m_parameter as IXPathNavigable;
        if (navigable != null)
        {
            m_parameter = navigable.CreateNavigator().Select(".");
        }
    }

    #region IXsltContextVariable Members

    public object Evaluate(XsltContext xsltContext)
    {
        return m_parameter;
    }

    public bool IsLocal
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    public bool IsParam
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    public XPathResultType VariableType
    {
        get
        {
            return XPathResultType.Any;
        }
    }

    #endregion
}

public class CurrentFunction : IXsltContextFunction
{
    private XPathNodeIterator CurrentNodeIterator;
    internal CurrentFunction(IXPathNavigable currentNode)
    {
        if (currentNode != null)
        {
            CurrentNodeIterator = currentNode.CreateNavigator().Select(".");
        }
    }

    public XPathResultType[] ArgTypes
    {
        get { return new XPathResultType[0]; }
    }

    public object Invoke(XsltContext xsltContext, object[] args, 
                         XPathNavigator docContext)
    {
        if (CurrentNodeIterator == null)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException("Current node is not set.");
        }
        return CurrentNodeIterator;
    }

    public int Maxargs
    {
        get { return 0; }
    }

    public int Minargs
    {
        get { return 0; }
    }

    public XPathResultType ReturnType
    {
        get { return XPathResultType.NodeSet; }
    }
}
```

Once you have that defined somewhere, you can do the following:

```
VariableContext vc = new VariableContext();
XmlNode nodea = doc.SelectSingleNode("Root/Start[1]");
vc.SetValue("a", nodea);
XmlNodeList selected = doc.SelectNodes("/Root/Item[@id = $a/@refId]", vc);
```

or use a custom-defined `current()` function:

```
VariableContext vc2 = new VariableContext();
XmlNode nodea2 = doc.SelectSingleNode("Root/Start[1]");
vc2.SetCurrentNode(nodea2);
XmlNodeList selected2 = doc.SelectNodes("/Root/Item[@id = current()/@refId]", vc2);
PrintNodeList(selected2);
```

Working ideone: http://ideone.com/7wsQ46

Comment: Thanks, getting nodeA is really a bit dangerous. The code I have posted is just a test sample, what I want to achive is more complex. Actually, I don't know where the element A is located beforehand and I can't change the second XPath depending on element A. This question is really more about XPath than .Net.

Comment: I see. Please see my modified answer above.

Comment: This doesn't work because VariableContext is not set to XPath in your example. To set it, an XPathExpression should be created and its SetContext method should be called. And docContext.Select(".") doesn't work either, it just returns to the same node where it is being evaluated. However, I get the idea - XPath has no idea of "starting node" and doesn't provide any means to return to it. To do so, a custom function or a variable should be used.

Comment: @XanderMK Sorry, there was a tiny but critical mistake in my example. `vc` needs to be passed as the second argument to `SelectNodes()`. There was also an issue with how I was implementing `current()`. The above should work now.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way:

```
XmlNode nodeA = doc.SelectNodes(@"Root/Start[1]")[0];
var selected = nodeA.SelectNodes("/Root/Item[@id = " + nodeA.Attributes["refId"].Value + "]");
```

Comment: Yes, I can, but I actually need to do that by only means of XPath, I can't change the second XPath from one node A to another.