# How to locate a node in the main document with an attribute that equals a value of an attribute of the currently selected node

Tags: xml, xpath

I am working through a list of nodes in a document, one node at a time.

During that processing, I need to select nodes from the wider document, using the value of a local attribute of the node I am processing.

I would like to have this expressed in a single XPath.

If I first get the local attribute value, I can insert it into the xpath, but I do not wish to do that, as I wish to have the Xpath to be self-contained.

The following document is an example of the kind of structure, but is just for illustration.

```
<root>
    <pageGenre>
      <page ref="attvalue1"/>
      <genre>horror</genre>
    </pageGenre>
    <pageGenre>
      <page ref="attvalue1"/>
      <genre>thriller</genre>
    </pageGenre>
    <pageGenre>
      <page ref="attvalue2"/>
      <genre>cooking</genre>
    </pageGenre>
    <book att="attvalue1">
      <author>Lovecraft</author>
    </book>
    <book att="attvalue2">
      <author>E.E. Smith</author>
    </book>
</root>
```

I first locate my list of nodes from the document with:

.//book

Then for each book node, I use that node to then get the value of `att`

./@att

which works each time.

What I want to be able to do, is to get all the page genres for the book via a single Xpath.

I have tried:

//pageGenre/page[@ref = ./@att]/../genre

This does not work, coming up blank.

If I use

[@ref = //@att]

I just get all the genres for all the book `att`s in the document.

If I first resolve the `./@att` value and then compose my Xpath, it works fine, but I do not want to have to "know" this needs to be done, as I want a list of XPaths to operate without any special cases using a generic dispatcher.

I have also tried `self::/@att`, but that is just the same as `./@att`, as one would expect.

Any ideas greatly appreciated.

Comment: so you want to select `<genre>` of `<page>` having ref attribute value equals to.. ? please continue the sentence. I can't clearly understand what you are trying to get from xml

Comment: I want to select <genre> of <page> having ref attribute value equal to the att of the current book node.

Comment: since book node is in different tree, I can't get what you meant by *current book node* (it's clear if `<book>` node is in the same tree as `<page>`). Good move by fixing xml structure BTW.

Comment: from XML sample in the question, which page should the XPath query returns?

Comment: That depends, and this is the nub.

If the current node is the node book/@att="attvalue1", then it should return a list of genre nodes, values horror and thriller. 

If one is at the second book node, it will return one genre node, value "cooking".

Note that I do use the current book node to make the query. I know this works, as if I substitute a text value instead of the attribute path ./@att, I get the correct answers I am looking for.

Comment: Just to fill out a bit more, to begin with I search for all book nodes, then iterate over those book nodes, using each node in turn to search for the page genres.

Comment: Ok, the last 2 comments plus the fixed XML sample cleared things up. Unfortunately, I can't come up with satisfying solution. All I know regarding this problem, posted in my latest answer. That's all

Answer (score 0):

You want to start the XPath query from a single node and backreferencing to it (to get the value of `att`), there is no bulit in function to do that. Following SO question is kind of confirming.

> "The only way I can see accomplishing what you describe below in the comments is to use LINQ to XML, XPath variables, or define your own current() function". [[.NET XPath starting from a specific element and backreferencing to it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15546111/2998271)]

And our try here :

```
//pageGenre/page[@ref = ./@att]/../genre
```

didn't work because `./@att` is selecting `att` attribute relative to current node, which is `<page>` instead of `<book>`. To reference `<book>` node in that part, you'll need to use `current()` function.

So in the end, the solution is to implement one of 3 ways offered in the link above, or if all of them turns out to be too complicated/overkill, just stick with storing value of `att` at the beginning of each iteration.

Comment: Thanks for the link - I am going to see if I can exploit VariableContext route.